Step Over (high bar) vs Step Into
What's the pro / con list for a step over vs step into bike?
As far as I can tell the step into bikes are just easier to get on without any disadvantages. Please correct me - does this design have drawbacks? Is it

heavier or
less aerodynamic or
less safe or
Harder to transport


TL;DNR, step though frames have no material disadvantage for typical riders.
From an engineering perspective the traditional two triangle design is very strong and stiff for its weight compared to the low bar/step though design. However, with modern materials and engineering design, the gap between the weight and stiffness of a frame has reduced significantly.
For competitive riding where every gram counts, the two-triangle design is still best for any given price point.
For an average person wanting a bike for typical average person's day to day riding, the weight difference between these designs is minimal or no-existent.  The stiffness of the step though frame is also negligibly lower.

I'd add that "step-over vs step-through" is a false dichotomy. Bikes come in a whole spectrum of stepthrough heights. The ones where the top tube is barely above the downtube (or outright missing) are indeed mechanically at a big disadvantage and need to be much beefier in the bottom bracket area to achieve comparable robustness to diamond frames. But just making the top tube a couple of centimeters lower already gives a lot of comfort benefit without compromising the mechanics in any relevant way.
